# ¿Cómo Funciona el MDI Parent PyQT5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Tengo un problema en Pyqt5, estoy intentando crear un MDI, pero cuando abro el formulario hijo dentro del padre, los metodos
del formulario hijo no Funcionan, tengo el siguiente ejemplo, cuando abro el formulario hijo ejecuto una funcion que cambio el texto del label con un button.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from FrmOne import Ui_FrmOne

class Ui_MainForm(object):
 def setupUi(self, MainForm):
    MainForm.setObjectName("MainForm")
    MainForm.resize(796, 414)

    self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(MainForm)
    self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 191, 421))
    self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(86, 101, 115);")
    self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
    self.frame.setObjectName("frame")

    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 60, 201, 51))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.OpenFormOne)

    self.mdiArea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea(MainForm)
    self.mdiArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 0, 611, 421))
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    self.mdiArea.setBackground(brush)
    self.mdiArea.setObjectName("mdiArea")

    self.retranslateUi(MainForm)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainForm)

    self.frmOne = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.subWindowOne = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow()

def retranslateUi(self, MainForm):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainForm.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainForm", "MDI Example"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainForm", "Form 1"))
    
def OpenForm(self,QMainWindow,QMdiSubWindow,Instance):
    
    if(QMdiSubWindow in self.mdiArea.subWindowList()):
        for w in self.mdiArea.subWindowList():
            w.hide()           
        QMdiSubWindow.show()
    
    if(QMdiSubWindow not in self.mdiArea.subWindowList()):
        QMdiSubWindow.closeEvent = lambda event: event.accept()
        window = Instance
        window.setupUi(QMainWindow)
        QMdiSubWindow.setFixedSize(601,421)
        QMdiSubWindow.setWidget(QMainWindow)
        QMdiSubWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(QMdiSubWindow)
        QMdiSubWindow.show()

def OpenFormOne(self):
    self.OpenForm(self.frmOne,self.subWindowOne,Ui_FrmOne())
```

Formulario Hijo

```
import sys
```

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_FrmOne(object):
def setupUi(self, FrmOne):
FrmOne.setObjectName("FrmOne")
FrmOne.resize(601, 421)

```
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(FrmOne)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 130, 171, 91))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
    font.setPointSize(26)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label.setFont(font)
    self.label.setObjectName("label")

    self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(FrmOne)
    self.button.setText("Press Me")
    self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210,80,190,30))
    self.button.setObjectName("btnTest")
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.ShowMessage)


    self.retranslateUi(FrmOne)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(FrmOne)

def retranslateUi(self, FrmOne):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    FrmOne.setWindowTitle(_translate("FrmOne", "Form 1"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("FrmOne", "Form One"))

def ShowMessage(self):
    self.label.setText("Clicked")
```

No me genera ningún tipo de error ya que no se ejecutan las funciones del formulario hijo.
Saludos.

Comment: Podrias proveer un [mre] para poder testear y encontrar la causa del error

Comment: He creado un ejemplo básico el link es el siguiente [Formulario padre](https://linkode.org/#QiaB7DtSLUd28ft5qjCq9) [Formulario Hijo](https://linkode.org/#uIwUf9JTm1NWdgOKji2p3) no edite la pregunta ya que me marca error por mucho codigo.

Comment: El codigo no depender de un enlace externo por lo que te recomiendo minimizar tu codigo sin que pierda la verificabilidad y asi podras publicarlo en el post. Yo no hago click en enlaces que desconfio.

Answer (score 0):

Resolví el error de con una linea de código, el problema era que no instanciaba a la clase hijo.

```
def OpenForm(self,QMainWindow,QMdiSubWindow,Instance):

if(QMdiSubWindow in self.mdiArea.subWindowList()):
    for w in self.mdiArea.subWindowList():
        w.hide()           
    QMdiSubWindow.show()

if(QMdiSubWindow not in self.mdiArea.subWindowList()):
    QMdiSubWindow.closeEvent = lambda event: event.accept()
    window = Instance
    window.setupUi(QMainWindow)
    QMdiSubWindow.setFixedSize(601,421)
    QMdiSubWindow.setWidget(QMainWindow)
    QMdiSubWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(QMdiSubWindow)
    QMdiSubWindow.show()
```

Con las siguientes líneas funciono el programa

```
def OpenFormOne(self):
#Instanciamos 
self.instanceFrmOne = UI_FrmOne()
self.OpenForm(self.frmOne,self.subWindowOne,self.instanceFrmOne)
```